# XCode 5.1 Beta 4 not recognizing iOS 7.1 Beta 4 test device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I never see anything other than the generic 'iOS Device' in the drop-down.

When I select that and run my app, I get the famous 'Xcode cannot run using the selected device. No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.'

The phone is correctly plugged in, and is recognized by latest iTunes etc.
XCode Version 5.1 (5B90f) (Beta 4)
iOS 7.1 (11D5134c) (Beta 4)
I also have XCode 5.0.2 installed.

Comment: Did you check the build for the carrier that you are from. Sometimes the wrong beta that is not for your phone can't be recognized.

Comment: @DavidH, I disagree with your comment. The question is not declaring ant type of technology covered under NDA, it is simply referring to build numbers which is all over internet and is somewhat public knowledge.

Comment: Generally in these situations I try rebooting either or both of the phone & computer.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey thanks for taking a look - to David's point, I did think twice about posting build number, but ultimately I agree with you. Nothing private there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click the "Use for Development" button next to your device listed in Xcode's organizer, you will have better luck making use of an iOS version meant for it.