# Upgraded to iOS7.1 now won't recognise device in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Everything was working fine, I then upgraded to 7.1 on one of my devices (iPad mini) now XCode won't recognise it.

I found this answer here

[XCode 5.1 Beta 4 not recognizing iOS 7.1 Beta 4 test device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391485/xcode-5-1-beta-4-not-recognizing-ios-7-1-beta-4-test-device)

But when I go to the organiser it just says

> The version of iOS on “Mini iPad” is not supported by this
>   installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of
>   the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK;
>   which is available here

But when I go to the link it just take me to the main screen of the Apple developer program (not signed in for some odd reason, when I'm already signed in), then what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade to XCode 5.1. The final version has been released.

Comment: I thought I would get an update notification from the App store? I prefer to upgrade things like that ,than downloading them directly from the developers portal.

Comment: True. Same here. Go to the Mac App Store, search XCode, and you will see the 'Upgrade' button. Click that, download around 2.3 GB, install and you're good to go

Comment: If you just see a install instead of upgrade, go ahead with that.

Comment: There's no upgrade button, just "Free" and then install, whys there no upgrade button?

Comment: Do not know, either 'Free'-'Install' or 'Upgrade' buttons were seen by various developers who work with me. But, all worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade iOS, you always need to upgrade even Xcode to the last version. Just open the MacAppStore to see the update.

The last version of Xcode is **Version 5.1 (5B130a)**

Comment: Just tried that, there's nothing there about an update.