# The version of iOS on [iphone's name] is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK - xcode 5 - ios 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7.1

I used Version 5.0 (5A1412), iphone 4 with ios 7.1 (11D169).
I use organizer to add device but xcode said "The version of iOS on “ducnm’s iPhone” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here."

Help me, please!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgraded to iOS7.1 now won't recognise device in XCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500996/upgraded-to-ios7-1-now-wont-recognise-device-in-xcode)

Comment: Please search for error messages before posting a question. Your aren't the 1st person to experience this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Xcode 5.1 to support iOS 7.1.

You can download it from the Mac AppStore app.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Xcode to  `Xcode 5.1`. check these link for [available SDK's in Xcode 5.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_1.html)